# What is the probability of the event?

Tags: probability

I am working on an assignment question and am having difficulty understanding it. My confusion comes from not understanding if there is any overlap between the different events?

> Let S be the sample space {a,b,c,d}. And the events A,B,C,D be defined as A = {a}, B = {a,b}, C = {a,b,c}, and D = {b,d}. We know that Pr(A) = 1/10, Pr(B) = 1/2, and Pr(C) = 7/10. What is the Pr(D)?

Am I supposed to be looking at the conditional probability between each of the given probabilities if so, what do I do after I have all 3? If thats not the way to solution any guidance would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: No, you are not supposed to be looking at conditional probabilities. The  key is in the wording. If a question says something like "_Given_ that the event A _occurred,_ what is the probability of event $B$?" (emphasis added), you are being asked for $P(B\mid A)$. If the question says something like "Given $P(A) = 0.1$ and $P(B) = 0.2$, find the probability of event $C$." you are being asked for the unconditional probability $P(C)$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I usually doubt my answer when I find the solution is too simple, but I have to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sample space $S = \big\{ a, b, c, d \big\}$, in the discrete probability space, we can calculate the probability mass centered at each atom:

$\mathbb{P}\big( \{ a\} \big) =  \mathbb{P}(A) = 1/10$

$\mathbb{P}\big( \{ b\} \big) =  \mathbb{P}(B\setminus A) =  \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A) =   1/2 - 1/10 = 4/10$.

$\mathbb{P}\big( \{ c\} \big) =  \mathbb{P}(C\setminus B) =  \mathbb{P}(C) - \mathbb{P}(B) =   7/10 - 1/2 = 2/10$.

Note that the event $D$ is the complement of $\{ a, c \}$, then 
$$\mathbb{P}(D) = 1 - \mathbb{P}\big( \{ a, c \}  \big) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\{ a\} ) - \mathbb{P}(\{ c\} ) = 1 - 1/10 - 2/10 = 7/10 . $$